# How can I design a better or functional database for a video site with what I have?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

First time designing a database after perusing some text on the topic.

I'm trying to design a database for a video/image website with only a few contributors. I've looked over a dozen examples of other people have similar problems, and I attempted to design my own.

There are users. The users have roles that dictates what permission they have. The user can upload files (video or image) and add category/tags to them.

This is what I have so far before I begin adding a comment system which SO has a few great examples out there already.

```
    USER PROFILE
    email
    username
    password
    gender
    date_of_birth
    date_created
    date_modified

    ROLES
    name
    user_profile_id

    FILE
    title
    size
    date_created
    date_modified
    description
    uploaded_by
    category_id
    tag_id

    CATEGORY
    name

    TAG
    name

    IMAGE
    width
    height
    file_id

    VIDEO
    length
    quality
    file_id
```

Are these tables appropriate for what I'm doing? Can you suggest some alteration for better performance, or a more efficient design to prepare for future changes?

Here's a visual: http://dbpatterns.com/documents/52eddecc9785db06b8f20775/

Comment: Seems alright. You can always look through examples at http://dbpatterns.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you forget to put the `user_profile_id` column in the `User Profile` table, as well as primary key fields for all the others? Also, given that the movie to tag relationship is many to many, you need a bridge table with movie_id and tag_id in the middle. With your current design a movie can have one tag only.